# Javascript - add row an existing table using document.execcommand but i made some mistake but i don't know where it is

Tags: javascript

I am developing editor but this range concept I can't understand.
I want to add first row of the table using exec command. I have inserted an image below.

[My expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alcye.jpg)

```js
 function addRow() {
    let range = document.createRange();
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    let el = document.querySelector("tbody");
    range.setStartBefore(el.firstChild);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    let b = `<tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>`;
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, b);
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" contenteditable="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Do you always want to add a new row as the first row of the table? Or depends on which row the cursor is on?

Comment: HI @Terry i want current cursor point add row using document.execcommand().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert HTML Text to any position.

```js
function addRow() {
    let el = document.querySelector("tbody");    
    let newRow = getRow(["Mary","Moe","mary@example.com"]);
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", newRow);
 }
 
 function getRow(dataArray) {
    let rowData = dataArray.map(data => `<td>${data}</td>`).join("");
    return `<tr>${rowData}</tr>`;
    
 }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" contenteditable="true">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: HI @Mohammad Faisal i wants to add row using document.execcommand()

Comment: @SanthoshD  But why do you want to use document.execcommand(), as it is Obselete feature declared by MDN.

Comment: You can see the docs here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands

Comment: Hi @Mohamam Faisal I try tried but i have one bug about that add row using execcommad. can you help me.